# Attempting to print filename causes exception

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
for p, n, f in os.walk('.')
    print(p, n, f)
```

Using Python 3.5.4 on Windows 10

This error is encountered when trying to print a file name that contains a (R) trademark character (specifically, the Intel Power Gadget shortcut):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>                                                       
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp43
7.py", line 19, in encode                                                                   
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]                         
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 22: character 
maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is the terminal encoding. Specifically, the use of the ConEmu program instead of `CMD.EXE`.

https://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html

You may set UTF8 as default encoding for all consoles starting in ConEmu. If you really like to do that, go to Settings/Environment page and add following line:

```
chcp utf8
```